# Removing one item from cart removes everything instead

Tags: php, html, css

I have a implemented a shopping cart function on my project website by following this guide video on YT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eAK8uYtNTy4&t=3528s and I am able to add items to the shopping cart and  remove items(kind of). However the remove function is very odd indeed,because it allows me to remove the item but when I clicked on it it also removes other items that is currently in the cart as well...

Here are my codes for the cart (cart.php)

```
<?php

    session_start();

    require_once ("conn.php");
    require_once ("component.php");
    



    if (isset($_POST['remove'])){
      if ($_GET['action'] == 'remove'){
          foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $key => $value){
              if($value["ID"] == $_GET['game_ID']){
                  unset($_SESSION['cart'][$key]);
                  echo "<script>alert('Product has been Removed...!')</script>";
                  echo "<script>window.location = 'cart.php'</script>";
              }
          }
      }
    }


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cart</title>
    <link rel="icon" href= "images/logoonly.png" type="image/jpg" sizes="16x16">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cart.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/sticky.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/ac84272c35.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Navigation -->
  <navbar>
    <section class="navbar-section" style="background-color: #252525; box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px black;">
      <div class="navbar-div">
        <div class="navbar-div-logo">
          <a href="index.html">
            <img href="index.html" class="logo-pic" src="images/logoonly.png" alt="">
            <img class="logo-name" src="images/logonameonly.png" alt="">
          </a>
        </div>
        <ul class="navbar-ul-links">
          <li> <a class="navbar-a-links" href="index.html">home</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="navbar-a-links" href="store.php">store</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="navbar-a-links" href="news.html">news</a> </li>
          <li> <a class="navbar-a-links" href="about.html">about</a> </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="navbar-div-cart-login">
          <a href="cart.html"><i class="fas fa-shopping-bag"></i></a>
          <a class="login navbar-a-links" href="login.html">login</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  </navbar>
<!-- /Navigation -->

<!-- Main Content -->
  
    <?php
    
       $total = 0;
       if (isset($_SESSION['cart'])){
           $ID = array_column($_SESSION['cart'], 'game_ID');
        include("conn.php");       
        $result = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from games where games.game_status = 1");  
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
          foreach ($ID as $game_ID){
            if ($row['game_ID'] == $game_ID){
                cartElement( $row['game_name'],$row['game_price'], $row['game_ID']);
                $total = $total + (int)$row['game_price'];
              }
             }
           }
              }else{
         echo "<h5>Cart is Empty</h5>";
         }

         

     ?>
      
      
    </section>
<!-- /Main Content -->

<!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
    <section class="footer-section" style="background-color: black;">

    </section>
  </footer>
<!-- /Footer -->

<script src="js/modal.js"></script>

<!-- Animate Show Panel -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(elementId) {
      document.getElementById("personal-info").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("acc-info").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "flex";
  }
</script>
<!-- /Animate Show Panel -->
  </body>
</html>
```

here are the components for the cart to display the items. (component.php)

```
<?php

function component($game_name, $game_price, $game_ID){
    $element = "      
        <form action=\"store.php\" method=\"post\">
            
            <div class=\"newrelease\">
            <div class=\"special-offer-description-div\">            
              <h5 name=\"game_name\">$game_name</input></h5>
              <button type=\"submit\" class=\"purchase\" name=\"add\">Add To Cart</button>
              <input type='hidden' name='game_ID' value='$game_ID'>
              <div class=\"price-div\">
                <h6>- 85%</h6>
                <p class=\"strikethrough\"  name=\"game_price\">RM$game_price</p>               
              </div>
            </div>                      
          </div>
        </form>
    ";
    echo $element;
}



function cartElement($game_name, $game_price, $game_ID){
    $element = "
    
    <form action=\"cart.php?action=remove&id=$game_ID\" method=\"post\">
    <section class=\"cart-section\">
    <div class=\"block\"></div>
    <div class=\"cart-div\">
      <h1>$game_name</h1>     
    <!-- Cart Games -->
      <div class=\"cart-items-div\">       

        <div class=\"description-div\">
          <div class=\"description\">

            <!-- Game Name -->
            <h2 class=\"game-title\"></h2>

            <!-- Game Description -->
            <div class=\"d\">
              <div class=\"details\">
                <h2>overall reviews:</h2>
                <h2>release date:</h2>
              </div>
              <div class=\"game-details\">
                <h2 style=\"color: #407AD3;\">very positive</h2>
                <h2>8 aug, 2018</h2>
              </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Game Specification -->
            <div class=\"compatibility\">
              <i class=\"fab fa-windows\"></i>
              <i class=\"fab fa-apple\"></i>
              <i class=\"fab fa-linux\"></i>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class=\"button-div\">

            <!-- Remove Game From Cart Button -->
            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger mx-2\" name=\"remove\"><i class=\"fas fa-trash-alt\" style=\"color: #FF4444\" ></i> </button>

            <!-- Purchase Game -->
            <button class=\"purchase\" input type=\"text\" value=\"1\">Purchase</button>

            <!-- Price -->
            <h3 style=\"border-right: none;\">$game_price</h3>

          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
                </form>
    
    ";
    echo  $element;
}
```

Comment: can you share the code of the button which is triggering the item removal Function  ?

Comment: Hi the button is in the component.php 

<!-- Remove Game From Cart Button -->
            <button type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger mx-2\" name=\"remove\"><i class=\"fas fa-trash-alt\" style=\"color: #FF4444\" ></i> </button>